# How can I obtain the id returned from the sp in my case

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

The place where I work at has this function that inserts an object information into a database, it returns the ID that was created on insert but.., they have this function returning as a bool, whether it was able to commit or not the transaction. I want to be able to use the ID that it returns too but I am not sure how to access it, it is assigning it to the entity but  the function returns a boolean.. so Its a bit confusing..

```
    //HERE IT IS SAVING THE ID INTO THE ENTITY BUT I AM NOT SURE HOW TO ACCESS IT ?.
        myentity.ObservationID = (System.Int32)_observationID;  

        myentity.AcceptChanges();
        OnDataRequested(new CommandEventArgs(commandWrapper, "Insert", entity));

        return Convert.ToBoolean(res);
```

In the submit button it is doing something like this

```
bool observationInserted = false;

 observationInserted = observationAdmin.Insert(observationEntity);  

if(observationInserted)
{
    I need to grab the observation id that was saved, the code in the inserting function seems
    to be doing this but it returns boolean, I need the ID and the boolean.

    then it will navigate somewhere appending the id.
}
```

NoteL After the call of the insert in the submit button it goes to some kind of transaction validation manager and from there it then calls the insert function with the transaction result.

Comment: Isn't the ID you are looking for saved in the entity object you passed in? If so, don't you just need to read observationEntity.ObservationID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observationEntity will be updated with the unqiue ID.

You can get it by refering to the ID property: `observationEntity.ObservationID`